# encodeToString is not a member of Base64?

Tags: scala, base64

In scala, I have parts of the code that's doing Base64.encodeToString & Base64.decode

```
 def genKeyAES(): String = {
    val keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
    keyGen.init(128)
    val key = keyGen.generateKey()
    val base64Str = Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded())
    base64Str
  }
  def loadKeyAES(base64Key: String): SecretKey = {
    val bytes = Base64.decode(base64Key)
    val key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "AES")
    return key
  }
```

The error says,

```
Type value encodeToString is not a member of object java.util.Base64
Type value decode is not a member of object java.util.Base64
```

The package I imported is `java.util.Base64`
    How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The API docs confirm what the compiler is telling you: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html . Try calling `getDecoder` and `getEncoder` first.

Comment: @danielnixon I have tried it but getEncoder is different from encodeToString.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded())
```

by

```
Base64.getEncoder.encodeToString(key.getEncoded())
```

and

```
Base64.decode(base64Key)
```

by

```
Base64.getDecoder.decode(base64Key)
```